# How can I find what triggered a dirtyforms popup?

Tags: jquery-plugins, datepicker, popupwindow, dirty-data, jquery-dirtyforms

I have a form that normally works with respect to dirtyforms. However, there is one circumstance where a jquery-ui datapicker calendar will pop up the "are your sure" dialog when a date is clicked.

I emphasize that this normally works correctly. The situation is related to the initial conditions of the form data source. Things work when the object being referenced is existing, but not if it is new. So I am sure somewhere there is a difference in the initial conditions of the form. But in theory the form should be identical.

How can I find what is causing the popup so I can fix my issue?

Comment: Some code will help us help you.

Comment: Well, I did find what was causing my problem by comparing the HTML of the working and non-working situations. (Not an easy task since there were many non-relevant differences.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did find what was causing my problem by comparing the HTML of the working and non-working situations. (Not an easy task since there were many non-relevant differences.)

Seems that the original coder did a strange thing. Left out some Javascript function declarations when the page was "new" but of course did not eliminate the calls on those functions.

So I guess that the javascript errors were the root cause. At least when I include those function declarations everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

By default, [most anchor links on the page will trigger the dialog](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms#default-anchor-ignoring-behavior). We don't have a hard-coded selector of all potential 3rd party widgets, you must manually take inventory of whether these widgets use hyperlinks and ignore them if they are causing errant behavior.

See [ignoring things](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms#ignoring-things) for more information.

I was unable to reproduce this behavior using Dirty Forms 2.0.0, jQuery UI 1.11.3, and jQuery 1.11.3. However, in previous versions of Dirty Forms, you can probably use the following code to ignore the hyperlink clicks from the DatePicker.

```
$('.ui-datepicker a').addClass($.DirtyForms.ignoreClass);
```